# SQL Server : calling code for a table that may not exist

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[tmp]', 'U') IS NULL OR 
   NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[tmp])
BEGIN TRY
    EXEC [dbo].[proc1]
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    print('error')
END CATCH
```

I am trying to run a piece of code to check if the table `tmp` doesn't exist or if it does exist but isn't populated. The first line should do what I want however when the table `tmp` doesn't exist I get an error saying the `table tmp doesn't exist` (for the `SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[tmp]` part) and won't run as a result. How can I get around this issue? I am Using Microsoft SQL Server 2017.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could nest the `IF` statements:

```
IF object_id('[dbo].[tmp]', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[tmp])
    BEGIN TRY
        EXEC [dbo].[proc1]
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        print('error')
    END CATCH
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    print('table does not exist')
END
```

Comment: This worked (without the extra end at the bottom) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should just do:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
                 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' 
                 AND  TABLE_NAME = 'tmp')
```

This query

```
SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[tmp]
```

causes an error if the table doesnt exists, 
because it runs a select on something none existant

Comment: This checks if it doesn't exist but doesn't check if it isn't populated